# Receive 32 bits in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I use a Nordic Semiconductor nRF52 to send a 32 bits value on my Android app, but it doesn't work everytime.
On the nRF52, I send an array of 4 bytes.

When I send 12345678 for example, I receive 12345678 on the phone : it's OK
When I send 24, it's OK too.
But when I send 7, or 107 for example, it does'nt work.

Do you have an idea why, please ?

On the Android app, I do :

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicNotified(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        int data = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0);

        String dataHexadecimal = Integer.toHexString(data);
        byte[] value = hexStringToByteArray(dataHexadecimal);

        int valeurFinale = 0;
        valeurFinale = value[3]*1000000 + value[2]*10000 + value[1]*100 + value[0];

        ControlBlinkyActivity.txtSiReception.setText("Reception : " + String.valueOf(valeurFinale));

        mCallbacks.onDataReceived(data = 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Possibly because it expects a 32 bit input, not 7

Comment: `valeurFinale = value[3]*1000000 + value[2]*10000 + value[1]*100 + value[0];`. That is not how the four bytes of an 32bit integer are build up. And you do not need that hexadecimal representation in between. But if you want to continue in this way then make the values hexadecimal too. Like value[3]*0x1000000 and so on.

Comment: `String dataHexadecimal`. Log that string so you see which four bytes come in. You only have to place them in a different sequence as you know.

Comment: 'Doesn't work"' is not a problem description. This code doesn't receive any 32-bit integers correctly, let alone 12345678 or 24. What exactly is wrong with `data` as you originally received it? And why are you fiddling around with it with all that incorrect code?

Comment: You are sure that int data does not contain the right value and that you have to change big endian to little endian or so?

Comment: Greenapps : when I log dataHexadecimal, I have 1100000a when I send 12345678 from the nRF52

Comment: EPJ : because I haven't found sample code to receive 32 bits correctly, soI ty to do it by myself :/

Comment: But where is the evidemce that `data` isn't already correct? What made you think you had to convert it to hex and then start multiplying bits of it by powers of ten? What is the problem here?

Comment: EPJ : when I send 12345678, then data is equal to 1312301580 on the app

Comment: Well that's strange, isn't it, because you clearly stated in your question that you can receive 12345678 correctly. Unclear what on earth this is all about.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the hexadecimal representation of 12345678 would be.

Comment: When I change from big endian to little endian, data is equal to 203569230 when I send 12345678.

Comment: If you compare values from endian conversions then please use hexadecimal representation. Then you can see if conversion is correct.

Comment: Greenapps : On the nRF52, when I send 12345678, it sends {12,34,56,78} in terms of bytes

Comment: Really? Hard to believe. Only if that was 0x12345678. And you did not tell us that from the start?

Comment: And when it has to send 107. What would it send?

Comment: When I convert from big endian to little endian, and then when I print the hexadecimal representation, I have c22384e. And : C -> 12, 22 -> 34, 38 -> 56, 4e -> 78. So I have o extract each byte, now, I guess !

Comment: You should show TWO hexadecimal values of course. Before and after conversion.

Comment: When I send 107, it send {00,00,01,07}, so {0,0,1,7}

Comment: Receiving 0c 22 38 4e for 12345678 or 12,34,56,78 looks ok then. So indeed you can multiply the individual bytes with 1000000, 10000 and 100. Well done.

Comment: To extract 0c, 22, 38 and 4e, do I have to manipulate data or dataHexadecimal ? When I do data >> 24, I obtain 12 (so it's OK), but when I do data >> 24, I obtain c22 (and I want to have only 22)

Comment: `When I do data >> 24, I obtain 12 (so it's OK), but when I do data >> 24, I obtain c22` ???? AND PLEASE USE HEXADECIMAL REPRESENTATION ONLY! Well.. the 24 is ok ;-). Did you mean 16 for the second shift?

Comment: ??? You already know. You used it: Integer.toHexString(data);

Answer (score 0):

Here is my functional code :

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicNotified(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        int data = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0);
        data = swap(data);
        String dataHexadecimal = Integer.toHexString(data);

        byte[] value = {0,0,0,0};
        value = hexStringToByteArray(dataHexadecimal);

        int finalValue = value[0]*1000000 +  value[1]*10000 +  value[2]*100 +  value[3];

        ControlBlinkyActivity.txtSiReception.setText("Reception : " + String.valueOf(valeurRecue));
        mCallbacks.onDataReceived(data = 1);
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me !